# Modify the header and footer

Tags: header-footer

I want to obtain in the header like the following

[image]

And in the footer

[image]

```
        \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.pt}% filet en haut de page
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.pt}% filet en bas de page

   \newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
   \newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}

   \setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

   \fancyhead[L,R]{\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
  \fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
   \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
   \rhead{\textbf{\thepage}} %{\textsl{\rightmark}}
   \lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%{\textbf{\thepage}}



\begin{document}
 \chapter{Semigroup theory and sesquilinear forms}
 \newpage
 cc

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\newpage
\bibitem{ax}{O. Rhandi,} {...,} ....
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> I don't understand how to add footer. Also after compilation I get in the header

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem right now?

Comment: Is https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage helping?

Comment: I don't know how to add footer. Also I want to omit chpater and include only the name of the chapter.

Comment: @Johannes_B Please see my edit.

Comment: `\fancyfoot[]{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `fancyhdr`:

[image: schuelerHeaderFooter2]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mwe}% Just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.pt}% filet en haut de page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.pt}% filet en bas de page% A line of zero width in invisible

%\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
%\newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}%That doesn't make any sense at all in a oneside document

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\lfoot{The title of the work}
\rfoot{Carl Capybara}
\cfoot{}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Manta Ray}
\blindtext
\section{Taxonomy}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Mobula}
\blindtext
\section{Life style}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does we use this `\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}` in `twoside`?  Also I think I should add `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.pt}`. Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Yes I mean in what case one should use it? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler Never. It is nonsense.

Comment: My question when exactely we add `\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{% \newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}`? Is it in twoside document ? Or in other case? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Schüler It does make absolutely no sense in a oneside document. It is still rubbish in a twoside document.

Answer (score 1):

With `scrlayer-scrpage` as shown in the [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage).

[image: schuelerHeaderFooter]

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline]{report}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\usepackage[markcase=noupper,% remove the uppercasing
automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\sffamily}

\ifoot*{Is life on Mars possible?}
\ofoot*{Walter Wombat}
\cfoot*{}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\setlength{\footheight}{24.0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Manta Ray}
\blindtext
\section{Taxonomy}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Mobula}
\blindtext
\section{Life style}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe Yes, sure. I forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: Good, I just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed anything really obvious.

Comment: @Johannes_B I want to use my codes. If I add `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
         \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}` the problem of header is solved. However, could you please help me in footer with my codes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Schüler `\rfoot{Name}`?

Comment: Please copy my codes and add \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} the problem of header is solved. However, even with \rfoot{Name} I don't get what I hope. Thank you for your help.